Can we add "#N/A" to the people picker field in the sharepoint list
Can we add "#N/A" to the people and groups field, as we don't want to leave it blank if there is no allocator.

Do you just want to show "#N/A" in a "list view" or "store/save" it as value in the column? It is not possible to save as value, instead you can save the name of default user (maybe service account) in the column value.

You could use JSON to set "#N/A" value when the person column is null.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Person.title]=='', '#N/A', '[$Person.title]'"
}


